# Can I use django-filebrowser with Django version 2.2.6?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-filebrowser

I am working on a Django app (version 2.2.6) and I want to use `tinymce.models` `HTMLFIELd` in my model. One of the requirements is that when the user clicks on the image tab it needs to pop up with an insert image URL field or let the user browse from their local files.

The default of `HTMLFIEL` is to render only the image URL option. For me to add the second option it seems that I need to install `django-filebrowser`. When I look at the docs it says the required Django version is higher than the Django version that I am using. I don't want to upgrade django. Is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [releases page](https://pypi.org/project/django-filebrowser/#history) of [django-filebrowser](https://pypi.org/project/django-filebrowser/#description) and click on older versions of the package, you'll see that the older versions of the package supports older versions of Django.

If you use `pip`, `pip install django-filebrowser` will automatically install the latest version of `django-filebrowser` that is compatible with your version of Django.

Comment: Got this error:
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'filebrowser' is not a registered namespace.
seetings.py
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
    .....
    'grappelli',
    'filebrowser',
]

Comment: That looks like it should be a separate Stackoverflow question.